# Azure Data Factory v2 portal is slow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

This is a generic question regarding development processes and using Azure Data Factory v2.

I am currently using the UI portal to set up and configure pipelines, datasets, activities, triggers, etc. but I am finding the lag time very long.

Is this the same for other users ?

What is the typical workflow for someone not using the portal ? (There seem to be no nuget packages for v2 and only powershell as the alternative to the UI portal.)

Answer (score 1):

The publish performance is low when you have large number of recourses (pipelines, datasets, etc). The PROD team is working on improving this.

And if possible, please use Chrome as browser.

Comment: Hi.
Thanks for the tip on using Chrome. I was using another browser but when switching to Chrome I noticed a huge difference.