# Azure data factory not loading

Tags: azure, browser, azure-data-factory

I am not able to open Azure data factory in any browser, it just keep loading from past 1 hour. I have tried refreshing and using other browser, is there any specific reason why it happens? All other services on azure portal is working fine.

Browsers which I have tried:

- Mozilla Firefox 65.0.2
- Internet explorer 9
- Microsoft Edge 42
- Opera Latest

For all of the above browsers all services are fine but when I click on "Author & Monitor", it opens up a new tab and keep loading.

[image]

Comment: Try to use Chrome, also try in an incognito window with all the browsers

Comment: Both Chrome and edge should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access ADF portal you should use Google Chrome as at this moment other browsers does not support this portal.

See the response for similar issue: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/26dd2244-efa2-4225-a32f-2f68d3a60139/data-factory-ui-is-not-loading .

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but somehow I was able to open ADF on Mozilla from another computer but not from my laptop. I am not sure about the reason yet. I will use Chrome from hereon.

Comment: That is right. Edge and Mozilla works since yesterday :) So as per today, you can use Mozilla, Edge and Chrome. Looks like, MS support reacts extremely fast!

Comment: Had this very issue trying to use Safari. Swapped to Chrome and all good. It's a pity they don't just show a message "Browser not supported" rather than continually showing a loading screen.

Answer (score 6):

I often experience this issue but not always.The azure data factory UI keep loading or  keep asking me to re-enter my account information. I fixed it by using `incognito` mode in the browser.

You could find many clues from this [MSDN case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/26dd2244-efa2-4225-a32f-2f68d3a60139/data-factory-ui-is-not-loading?forum=AzureDataFactory). Also,try Chrome browser according to this case:[Azure Data Factory v2 portal is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50988754/azure-data-factory-v2-portal-is-slow)

Comment: This worked for me and kind of made me think about the Chrome extensions, I disabled one by one to see what could be the problem and looks like for me it was "Cisco Webex Extension", now I'm sure that more extensions should be affecting this but it is not always, just sometimes. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you that worked - using firefox vs IE solved it.  I don't wish to use Chrome.

Comment: Both Chrome and Edge should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today too, I fixed it just by logging out from another account that I had log in moments before

Comment: Can you please explain further on how you logged out from the other account?

Comment: I had 2 account that were logged in, and for some reason it was creating an conflit, I just tried to log out from the one that I was not using, and then It was working fine

Comment: I know ADF can't handle more than one, account, I just cant find a consistent set of steps that i can follow to log out of an account. i.e. there is not logout button at adf.azure.com

Comment: In the top right corner, switch to the other account and then logout (click on the user and sign out), and then just loggin to the account where you want to work

Comment: these should do it

Comment: My issue, and the original posters issue, is that the ADF portal never comes up so there is no "logout" link

Comment: have you tried going to https://portal.azure.com/ and logout there?

Comment: I've tried logging out completely from all accounts (I have many) and clearing cookies and cache and I have the same issue. The only thing that works mostly consistently is opening InPrivate.

Answer (score 0):

This is the official solution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-ux-troubleshoot-guide?tabs=edge#azure-data-factory-studio-fails-to-load

Pay attention to the third party cookie settings.

ADF officially supports both Chrome and Edge. So you don't have to use Chrome. Firefox actually also works.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem from time to time. Just ***clear your browser cache*** when it happens again.

Here is the related issue:
[Azure Data Factory Not Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/933100/azure-data-factory-not-loading)